# Compile error on sub class which inherits generic base class

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance, interface

I'm developing a program where I must use a third party DLL-file which is published for `.NET Framework 4.8`.
**Note:** Any code must compile on that specific version.

In the DLL-file's namespace there are classes `FB` and `FC`, which implements the interface `IBlock`.
Very simplified they are defined as this:

```
interface IBlock { string Name { get; } }

class FB : IBlock { public string Name { get; set; } }
class FC : IBlock { public string Name { get; set; } }
```

I want to wrap each of these classes in separate "Info"-classes with a common base class.

I implemented this neat solution:

```
abstract class Info<TBlock> where TBlock : IBlock
{
    public TBlock Block { get; private set; }
    public Info(TBlock block) { Block = block; }
}

class FbInfo : Info<FB>
{
    public List<string> Inputs { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
    public FbInfo(FB fb) : base(fb) { }
}

class FcInfo : Info<FC>
{
    public List<string> Outputs { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
    public FcInfo(FC fc) : base(fc) { }
}
```

I can then do:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var fb = new FB();
    var fc = new FC();
    var infoFB = new FbInfo(fb);
    var infoFC = new FcInfo(fc);
    infoFB.Inputs.Add("Foo");
    infoFC.Outputs.Add("Bar");
    var names = $"FB name: { infoFB.Block.Name }, FC name: { infoFC.Block.Namne }";
}
```

This is all fine.

---

I also want the `Info` base class to have a property "Reader", which will be used to read XML-files for the specific IBlock instance.
I added this abstract class `Reader`:

```
abstract class Reader<TInfo>
{
    protected TInfo Info { get; set; }
    protected abstract void Read();
}
```

I changed the `Info` class accordingly:

```
abstract class Info<TBlock, TReader> where TBlock : IBlock where TReader : Reader<Info<TBlock, TReader>>
{
    public TBlock Block { get; private set; }
    protected TReader Reader { get; private set; }

    public Info(TBlock block, TReader reader)
    {
        Block = block;
        Reader = reader;

        Reader.Read();
    }
}
```

I then create a `FcReader` class:

```
class FcReader : Reader<FcInfo>
{
    public override void Read()
    {
        Info.Outouts.Add("Foo");
    }
}
```

Finally I changed the `FcInfo` class into:

```
class FcInfo : Info<FC, FcReader>
{
    public List<string> Outputs { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
    public FcInfo(FC fc) : base(fc, new FcReader()) { }
}
```

But in the `FcInfo` class I get a compile error which I don't understand and don't know how to solve, if even possible.

```
The type 'FcReader' cannot be used as type parameter 'TReader' in the generic type or method 'Info<TBlock, TReader>'.
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'FcReader' to 'Reader<Info<FC, FcReader>>'.
```

Is there any solution to this?
If so, how do I fix this?

I really want the `property Info` in the sub classes of `Reader`, to be of the same type as the `sub class of Info` are.

Comment: `FcReader : Reader<FcInfo>` But your constraint expects `TReader : Reader<Info<TBlock, TReader>>`, this is a variance problem. You'd need a recursive constraint `class Info<TInfo, TBlock, TReader> where TInfo : Info<TInfo, TBlock, TReader>` so you can define `where TReader : Reader<TInfo>` for `FcInfo : Info<FcInfo, FC, FcReader>`.